# Create a type with same keys as an Enum but each key has a different value

Tags: typescript, enums, record, typing

how can I create a type with the same keys as an enum, but each key has a different value, with this code :

```js
export enum DataType {
    TEST = "test",
    OTHER = "other",
}

type ReturnTypes = {
    [DataType.TEST]: number,
    [DataType.OTHER]: string,
};

type DataTypeResolver<T extends DataType> = T | Lowercase<T>;
```

I get an error `Type 'Lowercase<T>' cannot be used to index type 'ReturnTypes'.` when I try to use it in a method like this :

```
export async function getThing<T extends DataType>(dataType: DataTypeResolver<T>, text: string): Promise<ReturnTypes[Lowercase<T>] | null>
```

I want `dataType` to be both uppercase and lowercase version of the key.
*(Maybe I should stick to only Lowercase, but I'm not sure.)*

Comment: This seems like a really odd use case and I'm not sure why you are reaching for `enum` here.  Once you care about the actual value strings, it ceases to be really enum-like. Why not just use [a plain object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums)?  See [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wORKRW) or even [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1pGAW).  Does that work for you?  If so I could write up an answer explaining.  If not, what am I missing about your use case?

Comment: I want to keep an object listing every possible data type, but thanks for the tip of using a const object, I'll use this approach :)

Comment: Also, in my code, I have an overload for each possibility because I need to put documentation for every return type and how it's using the `text` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) are generally intended for situations where you only access the values via the enum keys; the actual values should be *opaque* to the TypeScript developer.  They are one of the few places in TypeScript where types are treated [*nominally*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) as opposed to [*structurally*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system).  In your `DataType` enum, even though `DataType.TEST` evaluates to `"test"` at runtime, it is an error to assign `"test"` to something that expects a value of the type `DataType`:

```
let example = DataType.TEST;
example = "test"; // error! Type '"test"' is not assignable to type 'DataType'.
```

If that error is a source of frustration as opposed to a desirable feature, it's an indication that you don't really want enums.  If you care about the particular values of an enum, it's an indication that you don't really want enums.  Since you are relying on the fact that the values are lowercase versions of the keys, and since you want to be able to assign `Lowercase<T>` to a place that expects `DataType`, it seems that you don't really want enums.

---

In such situations you can often [replace an enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums) with a [`const`-asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) object and get the desired behavior:

```
export const DataType = {
    TEST: "test",
    OTHER: "other",
} as const;

/* const DataType: {
    readonly TEST: "test";
    readonly OTHER: "other";
} */
```

The `const` assertion tells the compiler to keep track of the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the property values.  So `DataType` is known at compile time to be an object with a property with key `"TEST"` and value `"test"` and a property with key `"OTHER"` and value `"other"`.

Now it is fine to use the value `"test"` in a place that expects a value of the same type as `DataType.TEST`, because those are the same type:

```
let example = DataType.TEST;
example = "test"; // okay
```

Once you do that things become a lot easier. Your `ReturnTypes` type can stay the same,

```
type ReturnTypes = {
    [DataType.TEST]: number,
    [DataType.OTHER]: string,
};
```

and now you can define the `DataType` *type* as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the types of the keys and the types of the values of the `DataType` object:

```
type DataType = keyof typeof DataType | typeof DataType[keyof typeof DataType];
// type DataType = "test" | "other" | "TEST" | "OTHER"
```

And the compiler will be happy letting you index into `ReturnTypes` with `Lowercase<DataType>`:

```
declare function getThing<K extends DataType>(
    dataType: K, text: string): Promise<ReturnTypes[Lowercase<K>] | null> // okay
```

And you can see that `getThing()` behaves as desired:

```
async function test() {
    (await getThing("other", ""))?.toUpperCase(); // okay
    (await getThing("TEST", ""))?.toFixed(); // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=3&pln=24&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoJEpCADxgHs0AXM4AVzCQBERaQAVATxmQLFSwrgFEAylyQBeJACJa0WnIA0RYcJRcAEqIBKM+VVoALCGlXrSAXyskANhHoVwMR4fade-AHRjJANx2ZOSu7rIKSnIBSAD0sWRoaDQAhEjeyADkkVDKmUgYUEjAxkggUFDYoABG7rRUSLR8WZ7czZk+RF2EtoREFNR0SPBUwLlsHG38hoIiElwAXPKKuZZCJFq6ektyxmYWaj1lRSNjtEGEsQBUw6PjrRlLs6RoECAAJqP2POnzOyvKC7CV4fL4-Tb6HZ7czRIjWJBXWLdRzOUJgNzIWQPZp+eYXFzo8LLKIxeJIKgAaxAPG6TWmeicjDQwAyRVkzxIAG1sb5-FwALpLJhgarmQ7CbmTDI+CF6QVIXKYYBYQ7WC7XRrNJAM2hMlnNNl4YIAoXMUVoIGkaFoJaKjDKi7wxG0rU8zFICkQHhUABmmv4vomXi1AB9-RBA27OZ7vX66RG-W7+eqEvGg1N3TllEgw7tTDCc-I+XJC3JZXJuu8IPB7CBXkgfYxgPBaBhRkgsE4uCZ7VgADwAaRCimA7yKboAfAAKYLvKXNJYDlSNCi0W20JVYACUSwACskwIUIH2dXrWZyADJUADu5ng5WPA4n-MLTHs9gn3XKPGbDabLbbYAkBMMAwCnLcjXWJApxAa8QAwehO1obteynPN9lUeQ5C3LcAH4fHqABVGB+DQABhB9wMtEgYLghCOy7HtlTQ4tlzkbC8IIqgADEMHICB3iouEgA)